# A client of a Java ServerSocket does not/inconsistently receive a given number of bytes

Tags: java, tcp, ip, serversocket

While I was trying to send an Image (it's Bytes) and some other data over the Network via a Java ServerSocket, I found an interesting inconsistency in the code.

I ran the same server- and client code several times, and sometimes they both deadlocked (because I had a more complex protocol between them than just sending an image), sometimes they worked fine.

After simplifying it more and more, I found out that these programs will have a different outcome, depending on the delay I put between 2 instructions on the server side and the size of the buffer that is sent:

The server main methode:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4999);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        
OutputStream outStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter outWriter = new PrintWriter(outStream, true);
        
byte buf[] = new byte[2000]; // buffer size of 2000 as an example
        
System.out.println("sending: " + buf.length + " bytes");

outWriter.println(buf.length);
// If I put a delay here, for example 1000 System.out.println(1) statements, the client receives the buffer correctly, if not the client receives 0 bytes
outStream.write(buf);

clientSocket.close();
serverSocket.close();
```

The client main methode:

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("<address of the server>"), 4999);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

int len = Integer.valueOf(in.readLine());
System.out.println("expected length: " + len);
        
byte[] receiveBuf = clientSocket.getInputStream().readNBytes(len);
System.out.println("received buffer length: " + receiveBuf.length);
/* 
 At this point, the receiveBuf.length should be the expected size,
 but as soon as the server sends a to large buffer or the delay
 between the two send statements in the server is to small, the client prints that
 it received an incorrect number of bytes (always  less then the expected).

 With a buffer size of 20000 bytes I got the client to output that it received
 11808 bytes, which is 20000 - 2^13...
*/
        
clientSocket.close();
```

Now my problem is, that (if I researched correctly) this transaction uses TCP/IP, which means that in contrast to UDP, the data should always be correctly sent and received, no matter how slow or fast a device is, or how much delay you put in between instructions.
But, although the client does receive the correct length of the buffer (line 4 in client), it receives a buffer with a length that is less then the expected size(outputted by the client line 8), as soon as the length of the array that was sent by the server is to long (in my case around: size > 1443 bytes) or the delay between the two send statements in the server is to small(which should not matter in theory...).

Things I have to mention: The exact number of bytes that the server has to send, so that the client says it received a wrong number of bytes may vary with the client speed (slow Pc, fast Pc), but 2000 bytes should already be enough (with that i could reproduce it on every device I have (Laptop, VM, Pc)). The error does not appear, if server and client are the same device!

So my question is: How can the result (and integrity) of this TCP transaction depend on the execution speed of the program on the server side and size of the buffer that is sent?

**PS:** By execution speed, I mean the optional added `System.out.println()` statements in the server program, which sometimes somehow determine whether the client receives the buffer successfully or not.

**Edit:**
Just by running the server on my pc, and the client on my Laptop while varying the sent buffer size and repeating each for 3 times, I got these outputs:

*server: "sending: 2000 bytes"*
*client: "expected length: 2000" "received buffer length: 0(first try, 2000 second try, 0 third try)"*

*server: "sending: 8192 bytes"*
*client: "expected length: 8192" "received buffer length: 6(first try, 0 second try, 8192 third try)"*

*server: "sending: 20000 bytes"*
*client: "expected length: 20000" "received buffer length: 11808(first try, 11808 second try, 11808 third try)"*

*server: "sending: 100000 bytes"*
*client: "expected length: 100000" "received buffer length: 91808(first try, 91808 second try, 91808 third try)"*

*server: "sending: 1000000 bytes"*
*client: "expected length: 1000000" "received buffer length: 998540(first try, 1000000 second try, 991808 third try)"*

Comment: I don't get it. The buffer in your first sample code is empty - why?

Comment: Because the content of the buffer does not matter in this problem, it could also be filled with random numbers etc.. The point is that as soon as it reaches a certain size, the client says that is received 0 bytes.

Comment: You're also going to corrupt your output as you're writing a *binary* value (the length) with a `Writer`. `Writer`s are for `String`s

Comment: I am sending the expected size as a Integer string (with a new line at the end), and I know this is not the best solution, but why should that be speed dependent? Meaning sometimes it works, sometimes it does not.

Comment: Actually you're writing an `int`. You might get away with it here but really it should be done in a proper stringified way. But you really need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I've tested it and adjusted my question, the given programs should be a minimal reproducible example. (If the described behavior does not work, then increase the size of the buffer that is sent by the server)